# I'm using html and have two buttons. I want these buttons to have different typeWriter() function outputs

Tags: javascript, html

Please keep in mind I am a beginner. It would be very helpful if you could avoid complicated terminology. The issue is that I cant give buttons specific functions. I tried using id and name. I thought it would have been easier if I had the typewriter effect go after pre-existing text but it didn't work and both inputs (buttons) use the second command. All I really need is a way to link the buttons to a specific function.
I originally didn't plan on using the method of having the 1 and 2, so if you have a method which is only typewriter that would work for me as well.

```js
var i = 0
var x = document.getElementById("button1")
var txt = 'button 1';
var speed = 80;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("button1").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}[]
var i = 0
var x = document.getElementById("button2")
var txt = 'button 2';
var speed = 80;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("button2").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}[]
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>name</h1>
  <button style="font-size:25px" onclick="typeWriter()" id="#button1">button number 
    1</button>
  <button style="font-size:25px" onclick="typeWriter()" id="#button2">Button number 2</button>
  <h1 id="button1"> l</h1>
  <h1 id="button2"> 2 </h1>
  <h3 style="color:white;"></h3>
```

Comment: _“The issue is that I cant give buttons specific functions”_ - right now, the problem is probably rather that you are _overwriting_ your function, by using the exact same function name a second time.

Comment: Just a suggestion: you should care a bit more the indentation, in the way you written your code it's quite hard to understand it, to figure out if/where is the bug and to help for a solution.

Comment: Also try to use "let" instead of "var", good to have the habit since your are beginner. Declare variables inside of the function, not outside.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a function for each button, you can reuse the same function and pass it the text and target element, like so:

```js
const speed = 80;

function typeWriter(elementId, text, i = 0) {
  const element = document.getElementById(elementId)
  if (i < text.length) {
    element.innerHTML += text.charAt(i);
    setTimeout(() => typeWriter(elementId, text, ++i), speed);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>name</h1>
  <button style="font-size:25px" onclick="typeWriter('button1', 'some text for button 1')" id="#button1">button number 
    1</button>
  <button style="font-size:25px" onclick="typeWriter('button2', 'some text for button 2')" id="#button2">Button number 2</button>
  <h1 id="button1">l </h1>
  <h1 id="button2">2 </h1>
  <h3 style="color:white;"></h3>
```

Comment: Thank you this is really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

OK so I think you want certain text, associated with a certain button somehow, to be "typed out" in the h1 tags like a typewriter. Let me know if its something else. If so, you need to add parameters to the function, instead of defining it twice, like the following:

```js
function doTheTyping(id, txt) {
  var speed = 80;
  var i = 0
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  function typeWriter() {
    if (i < txt.length) {
      el.innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
      i++;
      setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
    }
  }
  if(el) typeWriter();
}

$button1.onclick = function() {
  doTheTyping("button1", "button 1");
};

$button2.onclick = function() {
  doTheTyping("button2", "button 2");
};
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>name</h1>
  <button style="font-size:25px" id="$button1">button number 
    1</button>
  <button style="font-size:25px" id="$button2">Button number 2</button>
  <h1 id="button1"> l </h1>
  <h1 id="button2"> 2 </h1>
  <h3 style="color:white;"></h3>
  </div>
```

a parameter is like a variable that changes for each function. Notice now there is a parent function, doTheTyping, which has all of the variables (especially i) reset, and within that function itself does the setTimeout start (and increment i), but before i was being incremented by one of the buttons, and by the time it was done, no others would work.

The problem before was that the same variables were being defined twice. If a function or variable has the same name as another one, it has to be renamed, if a different result is expected for it, *or* it can be reduced to one function that can have different behavior based on the parameters.

Another thing is I noticed the buttons themselves were assigned IDs, but those were never used, so in general the onclick events were moved into a JavaScript tag, to give some more flexibility, instead of having everything inside of the quotes on the HTML page itself
Let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 1):

You can use a common parametric function called by each button.

Something like that:

```
    function toButton1() {
      typeWriter('button 1', 'button 1', 0, 80);
    }

    function toButton2() {
      typeWriter('button 2', 'button 2', 0, 80);

    }

    function typeWriter(id, txt, i, speed) {
      if (i < txt.length) {
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
        i++;
        setTimeout(typeWriter(id, txt, i, speed), speed);
      }
    }

    <button style="font-size:25px" onclick="toButton1()">button number 1</button>
    <button style="font-size:25px" onclick="toButton2()">Button number 2</button>
    <h1 id="button1"> l</h1>
    <h1 id="button2"> 2 </h1>
```

Live Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ge9sm8

Answer (score 1):

Since you're new to programming I'll do my best to answer this as clearly as I can. Below you will find **a** solution to your question, but note that there are many other possible (and probably better) solutions you could come up with.

Most of the changes to the javascript code are explained in the comments that correspond to the particular lines, but there are a few things I want to explain first:

- I changed your uses of `var` to either `let` or `const`. These are ways to declare variables introduced with one of the more recent versions of JavaScript, and essentially they are safer ways of declaring variables than `var`. The main difference between `let` and `const` is that varibales defined with the `const` keyword are **constant**, meaning they cannot be assigned a different value later on in the code. This is fine for the `txt`, `speed`, and `button` variables as you don't need to change them later on, but note that for `i`, which you're changing within the main writing function I used `let`, telling the engine that this is a variable that is expected to change. However, this is mostly a thing of personal preference, and it's ok to use `var` instead.
- I'm not sure if you're familiar with parameters, but essentially they allow you to pass values into a function to change how that function acts. They're defined in the parenthesis ("(...)") after the function name and can then be used anywhere within the body of that function. In this example I'm using them to pass the number of the button, so that I can use the number to adapt the text and get the appropriate element. Notice that in the HTML code, I pass the number 1 and 2 to the function in the onclick handle, to do just that

```js
/**
 * Run a typewriter effect for the element associated with the index parameter passed 
 * into the function. 
 * 
 * @param {Number} index The index of the element to associate the animation with
 */
function typeWriter(index) {
    let i = 0

    // I use the ` symbol here as it allows me to insert a varibale into the string.
    // When I then surround [index] with ${} it tells the engine to grab the current
    // value of the [index] variable and replace the "${index}" definition with its 
    // current value. That way this line generates a different text based on what 
    // index is passed in as a parameter
    const txt = `button ${index}`;
    const speed = 80;

    // The logic for using the backticks (`) and the ${} here is the same as in the 
    // "const txt = " line above. Inserting the current value of index into the string
    // means that this line fetches a different element based on what is provided as the
    // index parameter of the function. 
    const button = document.getElementById(`button${index}`)
    
    // Since the above line gets the element dynamically based on the input it is possible
    // that the input will not correspond to an element. If that's the case then button 
    // will be [null] and we want to just bail out of this whole function and not do 
    // anything else
    if (!button) { return }

    // Here I reset the innerHTML of the element. It's up to you if you want to do this
    // or just keep adding to the text already in the element, but I found this visually 
    // more pleasant. 
    button.innerHTML = ""

    // Here I just wrapped the code you had in the [typewriter] function before inside a 
    // new nested function so that you can still call it from the [setTimeout] call
    function writeLetter() {
        // As above we first ensure that [button] is a valid element before we do 
        // anything else.
        if (!button)  { return };

        if (i < txt.length) {
            button.innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
            i++;
            setTimeout(writeLetter, speed);
        }
    }

    // Here I just need to call the above defined function once to kick off the 
    // writing effect.
    writeLetter()
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Typewriter</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <h1>Typewriter</h1>
  <button style="font-size:25px" onclick="typeWriter(1)" id="#button1">button number 1</button>
  <button style="font-size:25px" onclick="typeWriter(2)" id="#button2">Button number 2</button>
  <h1 id="button1">1</h1>
  <h1 id="button2">2</h1>
</div>
```

I hope that was helpful. Of course if you have any questions feel free to comment on my post and I or someone else will do our best to answer. Good luck in your coding career :)

-- Jakub

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, you showed me some very neat tricks. I intend on using this to insert text, how would I do that?

Comment: @AndresAGUDELO I'm not sure what you mean. Could you elaborate a bit on what you're trying to do please?